# Insert null in a database

Tags: java, oracle, mybatis

I have retrived a `List<SomeBean>` using a `select` statement. Now, I am trying to `insert` the same. This insert statement is working fine; however, I am not able to insert null values. The table does not have any `NOT NULL` constraints. The following exception is raised:

`org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Error setting null for parameter #4 with JdbcType OTHER . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different jdbcTypeForNull configuration property. Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type`

How can I insert null values in mybatis?

Comment: what will happen if you not set it's value in your `insert` statement ???!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When setting a null parameter into a Prepared Statement or a Callable Statement MyBatis needs to know the jdbc type. Like this:

```
#{myNullParamenter, jdbcType=VARCHAR2}
```

Comment: Thx! was going through the same in mybatis tutorial.`NOTE The JDBC Type is required by JDBC for all nullable columns, if null is passed as a value. You can investigate this yourself by reading the JavaDocs for the PreparedStatement.setNull() method.`

Answer (score 6):

insert this line into the configuration file of MyBatis:

```
<settings>
        <setting name="jdbcTypeForNull" value="NULL" />
</settings>
```