# uncategorized SQLException for SQL[]; SQL state [null]; Error code [17004]

Tags: java, spring, oracle, mybatis

```
<insert id="insertQuery" parameterType="java.util.HashMap"> 
INSERT INTO tcpgp (id , name, phone) VALUES (#{id}, #{name}, '')
```

Using Mybatis and spring, insert into table.

When I saw logs, this message came out "DB insert error / Error setting null for parameter #3 with JdbcType OTHER. Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different jdbcTypeFor Null configuration propery. Cause:java.sqlSQLException"

I expect it is because of Spring Framework.
I need to insert null data into a phone column.
The phone column allows null values.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Do you have table with name _table_? Maybe those answers will be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/a/16191389/4430543
http://stackoverflow.com/a/8466117/4430543

Comment: No , it is a different name

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the phone column, what about just to execute this query:

`INSERT INTO tcpgp (id , name) VALUES (#{id}, #{name})`

Answer (score 0):

When you use `mybaits` insert null value, you need to specify the column's `jdbcType`.

You can update your SQL like this:

```
INSERT INTO tcpgp (id , name, phone) VALUES (#{id}, #{name}, #{phone,jdbcType=VARCHAR})
```